# Route::Resource en api.php solo puede hacer HEAD y GET, no puede hacer POST (Error 405)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Siguiendo un tutorial me di cuenta de que mis rutas parecen tener un error extraño, no pueden hacer POST cuando en el video del señor estas SI pueden hacer POST

Estas son mis rutas en api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

//Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
//    return $request->user();
//});

Route::resource('buyers', 'Buyer\BuyerController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);

Route::resource('categories', 'Category\CategoryController', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);

Route::resource('products', 'Product\ProductController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);

Route::resource('transactions', 'Transaction\TransactionController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);

Route::resource('sellers', 'Seller\SellerController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);

Route::resource('users', 'User\UserController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit']]);
```

Cuando hago php artisan route:list, me dice que solo pueden hacer HEAD y POST

Esto es lo que me muestra el comando php artisan route:list

```
+--------+----------+----------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                        | Name               | Action                                                       | Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | buyers                     | buyers.index       | App\Http\Controllers\Buyer\BuyerController@index             | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | buyers/{buyer}             | buyers.show        | App\Http\Controllers\Buyer\BuyerController@show              | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | categories                 | categories.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Category\CategoryController@index       | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | categories/{category}      | categories.show    | App\Http\Controllers\Category\CategoryController@show        | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | products                   | products.index     | App\Http\Controllers\Product\ProductController@index         | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | products/{product}         | products.show      | App\Http\Controllers\Product\ProductController@show          | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | sellers                    | sellers.index      | App\Http\Controllers\Seller\SellerController@index           | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | sellers/{seller}           | sellers.show       | App\Http\Controllers\Seller\SellerController@show            | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | transactions               | transactions.index | App\Http\Controllers\Transaction\TransactionController@index | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | transactions/{transaction} | transactions.show  | App\Http\Controllers\Transaction\TransactionController@show  | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | users                      | users.index        | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@index               | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | users/{user}               | users.show         | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@show                | api        |
```

Entonces llego a la parte de usar Store con postman, y no funciona, simplemente tira un error 405

Esto es lo que tengo en mi modelo de User

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    const USUARIO_VERIFICADO = '1';
    const USUARIO_NO_VERIFICADO = '0';

    const USUARIO_ADMINISTRADOR = 'true';
    const USUARIO_REGULAR = 'false';

    protected $table = 'users'; 

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    //Atributos que se pueden editar directo
    protected $fillable = [ 
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'verified', 'verification_token', 'admin',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'verification_token',
    ];

    //Estatus del usuario verificado
    public function esVerificado(){
        return $this->verified == User::USUARIO_VERIFICADO;
    }

    //Estatus del usuario administrador
    public function esAdministrador(){
        return $this->admin == User::USUARIO_ADMINISTRADOR;
    }

    //Hacer token de verificacion
    public static function generarVerificacionToken(){
        return str_random(10);
    }
}
```

Este es el metodo store con el problema

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    $campos = $request->all();
    $campos['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
    $campos['verified'] = User::USUARIO_NO_VERIFICADO;
    $campos['verification_token'] = User::generarVerificacionToken();
    $campos['admin'] = User::USUARIO_REGULAR;

    $usuario = User::create($campos);

    return response()->json(['data' => $usuario], 201);
}
```

Estoy usando Laravel Framework 5.4.36

Comment: Estás limitando los métodos a los que acceden las rutas con `['only' => ['index', 'show']]`. Para acceder al método store, que correspondería a una petición POST, tendrías que agregarlo al array

Comment: En user es Route::resource('users', 'User\UserController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit']]). Ahi esta tirando 405. El problema es un user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que debía hacer php artisan route:clear

Si ustedes hacen rutas nuevas usando api.php, corran ese comando todo el tiempo porque Laravel tiene la mala costumbre de guardar cosas en cache

Comment: Tu respuesta no se entiende, ¿por qué debes ejecutar de nuevo el comando que nos mencionas en la pregunta? o borraste la cache, por favor se claro

Comment: querrás decir `route:clear` pero el caché de rutas no se genera por voluntad propia. Es opcional justamente porque resulta molesto en desarrollo